MassTransit Saga State Machine activity How to use IStateMachineActivity Faulted?
MassTransit Saga State Machine activity
How to use IStateMachineActivity Faulted?
To ensure exceptions trigger the Faulted method in IStateMachineActivity when executing Execute, you may need to configure error handling appropriately for unified exception handling.
MassTransit Saga State Machine activity How to use IStateMachineActivity Faulted?

If you're building a regular activity, you simply pass calls to Faulted to the next activity in the pipeline as shown in the built-in activities.
public Task Faulted<TException>(BehaviorExceptionContext<TSaga, TException> context, IBehavior<TSaga> next)
    where TException : Exception
{
    return next.Faulted(context);
}

public Task Faulted<T, TException>(BehaviorExceptionContext<TSaga, T, TException> context,
    IBehavior<TSaga, T> next)
    where T : class
    where TException : Exception
{
    return next.Faulted(context);
}

If you're building an activity that only handles exceptions (faults) in the behavior, you'd implement it similar to the faulted action activity. This isn't common, as the built-in activities usually meet the needs, but either type can be created.

I tried to inherit IStateMachineActivity<SagaState,T> and implement Execute and Faulted, but Faulted did not catch the exception thrown by Execute

It doesn't work that way, Faulted isn't going to catch anything for the current activity. If you want to handle exceptions, use try/catch instead.
